Is there a way to refresh the targeted values in a sharepoint list field after workflow is finished?
Due to the limitation of using calculated fields on lookup columns, I created a flow on SharePoint Online to update a field with the value we needed from this lookup. Unfortunately due to human error or limitation, pressing F5 until it shows the populated field is not feasible.
Is there a way out there or a concept that can "refresh" the field in question or list after the workflow finishes?
The only archaic method I considered using was to get an email notification so I can start the next step in our work process (we have other lists that depend on this field being populated).
Thank you.

There is no built-in way to refresh the targeted values in a SharePoint list field after a workflow is finished. One option is to set up an email notification to alert you when the workflow is finished, so you can manually refresh the field.

Thanks, that's pretty much what I've had and we'll just have to go with a user process
